# How to Get query_posts from two 'meta_value' in infinite scroll Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-query

I am trying to get post by two meta value key, and is working fine in normal page but is not working on infinity. The problem is that, there is no post request received when the page is scrolled.

Please see the code below. I have done many search on Google but I did not get any answer please help

```
function wp_infinitepaginate(){
$args = array( 
    'cat' => $cats,
   'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'value' => 'India'
    ),
    array(
        'value' => 'Hindi'
    ), 
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
     <div class="art" >
    <a class="title" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; 
        exit;
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');  
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');
```

Comment: please describe the details on "what is not working", any error message? And what is the expected behavior for working?

Comment: Not gating post with that values? i didn't received any error msg

Comment: Thnks friends i fixed my problem my self

Comment: Good, it will be nice if you can post the answer also.